# How to refresh token on AWS Amplify using flutter

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

So I have been trying to refresh my Auth token using flutter but without any success.

After a long time with the app on screen the token expires and all requests get rejected.

I called `await Amplify.Auth.getPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito.pluginKey).fetchAuthSession();` and the response was the following:

```
CognitoAuthSession ({
  "isSignedIn": false,
  "userSub": "AWSErrorResult<String, SignedOutException> {\n  \"exception\": {\n    \"message\": \"No user is currently signed in\"\n  },\n  \"stackTrace\": null\n}",
  "userPoolTokens": "AWSErrorResult<CognitoUserPoolTokens, SignedOutException> {\n  \"exception\": {\n    \"message\": \"No user is currently signed in\"\n  },\n  \"stackTrace\": null\n}",
  "credentials": "AWSErrorResult<AWSCredentials, InvalidAccountTypeException> {\n  \"exception\": {\n    \"message\": \"No identity pool registered for this account\",\n    \"recoverySuggestion\": \"Register an identity pool using the CLI\"\n  },\n  \"stackTrace\": null\n}",
  "identityId": "AWSErrorResult<String, InvalidAccountTypeException> {\n  \"exception\": {\n    \"message\": \"No identity pool registered for this account\",\n    \"recoverySuggestion\": \"Register an identity pool using the CLI\"\n  },\n  \"stackTrace\": null\n}"
})
```

If I try to call `await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();` after calling `fetchAuthSession()` I get the response `No user is currently signed in`

So, AWS documentation is very shallow on this and it even mentions auto refresh stuff, but I can`t seem to use that https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/advanced/q/platform/flutter/#token-refresh

Comment: Hey Fernando, are you using a federated provider e.g. Okta, Auth0 etc.? If not, can you please try `Amplify.Auth.currentSession()`? That auto refreshes the token in JS but not sure if it works as such in Flutter SDK too (should do). If so, auto refresh is only available for 'regular' Cognito user pool login.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I'm not using federated providers, and that method is not available for flutter SDK.